# Monit vs Source Control: permission problems

Tags: version-control, mercurial, monit

I'm trying to be good. That's my big mistake.

I'm being good by having process monitoring: I have monit watching some key processes, and restarting them if they fail.

I'm being good by not running as root: Monit runs a web-server, and I don't want it to run as root in case there is a security issue. So, I have a special 'monit' user, that has the permissions required to start and stop some key processes, and that is about it.

The monit process reads from a ~monit/.monitrc file, and monit insists that the file is only readable by the the user it runs as - i.e. the monit user.

I'm being good by storing all my operational scripts and configurations in source-control (mercurial), so I can rebuild machines with the same specs. I, or other devs, check-in changes to the scripts to source control, and then I pull the results onto the production machine. Symbolic links point from ~monit/.monitrc into the source control directory.

However, that's where it all falls down - the source control directory is written to by Mercurial when I pull the latest scripts, but the pull command isn't running as monit, so the monitrc file is writable by another user... which monit doesn't like, and won't run.

I can constantly chowning and chmodding the monitrc file before and after each pull, but that is fraught with oversights.

I can't see how to ask monit to relax about ownership. I can't see how sticky bits will help.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You could always make `hg` into a script that calls `hg` and then deals with the permissions. Something like

```
!#/bin/bash
/usr/bin/hg.bin $@ && chmod 400 ~monit/monitrc && chown monit ~monit/monitrc
```

Save the script as `/usr/bin/hg` (or wherever your `hg` binary is installed) and

```
mv /usr/bin/hg /usr/bin/hg.bin
chmod 744 ~monit/monitrc
```

Assuming your normal user has permissions to run the `chmod` and `chown` commands, that should work.